# Comparing two Arabic-language string values in PHP?

Tags: php, string, arabic, strcmp

I'm having problems trying to compare two Arabic-language strings in a PHP script to see if they match.  I've tried setting the internal encoding to UTF-8 with mb_internal_encoding, I've tried a simple if ($x == $y) expression, I've tried strcmp()... no dice.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Does PHP have problems with doing string comparisons with non-English text?

Thanks!

Here is a code excerpt:

```
             // Chop up HTML content into bits

             $threadPieces = explode('</div>', $innerHTML);

             // Chop up the HTML bits into data entries

             $strippedThreadPieces = strip_tags($threadPieces[1]); 
             $threadInfo = explode('-', $strippedThreadPieces);

             $threadTitleExists = trim($threadTitleExists, 'thread_title_');

             $postername = "مراسل";

             if (($threadTitleExists > 100000) && ($threadInfo[0] === $postername))
             {
             echo 'Thread title:';
             echo strip_tags($threadPieces[0]);
             echo '<p>';
             }
             else
             {

             }
```

Comment: do both strings have the same encoding? Could you post the snippet you use to compare includiing your calls to mb_ functions?

Comment: What you need is `mb_strcmp()` which does not exist in PHP for some reason. Maybe this might be helpful: http://pastebin.com/d9kyBjBr

Comment: As long as they are both using the same encoding, you should be able to use `===` just fine

Comment: From where are coming the two strings? This is the question you have to answer to figure out if at least your encoding is correct

Comment: A way to transport the strings from you to us in a binary safe fashion is to use base64_encode(). Then someone can inspect the strings. Keep in mind, just because 2 strings visually render on your computer monitor the same, doesn't mean they have the same binary representations.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected as much... One string is being grabbed from an HTML <tag> and one string is being pasted directly into the PHP script.  It sounds like base64_encode() is going to be the most reliable solution... I wasn't aware of its existence.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everybody... I'm going to try some of the above and if I still have issues, I will post an excerpt of the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the character set of your php file, try to save it using utf-8 character set.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was using the function [mb_ereg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php) which is regular expression match with multibyte support.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I'm using

```
//from http://www.phperz.com/article/14/1029/31806.html
function mb_split_str($str) {
    preg_match_all("/./u", $str, $arr);
    return $arr[0];
}

//based on http://www.phperz.com/article/14/1029/31806.html, added percent

function mb_similar_text($str1, $str2, &$percent) {
    $arr_1 = array_unique(mb_split_str($str1));
    $arr_2 = array_unique(mb_split_str($str2));
    $similarity = count($arr_2) - count(array_diff($arr_2, $arr_1));
    $percent = ($similarity * 200) / (strlen($str1) + strlen($str2) );
    return $percent;
}
```

So

```
$var = mb_similar_text('عمار', 'ياسر', $per);
output: $var = 2, $per = 25
```